# link against external libraries inside a openCL kernel program

Tags: c, opencv, parallel-processing, opencl

I have a openCV code written which I need to parallize to improve performance. I need to know how can I call openCV functions inside a openCL kernel.

Is there any way to do it, if yes/no can I please be pointed to the relevant lit/ tutorial?

Thanks for help.

Cheers,
Paras

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot link against libraries from within your OpenCL kernel.

However, OpenCL absolutely excels at image processing work, so it is likely that some of what you want from OpenCV has already been implemented by somebody using CL.  Perhaps if you elaborate on what exactly you need out of OpenCV, some kind hacker hereabouts can point you at an implementation that you can incorporate into your program.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV itself has a [GPU module](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU) that reimplements several of it's image processing algorithms on the GPU.

[Check the docs!](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html)

Comment: You probably should mention that OpenCV's GPU module is based on CUDA and therefore requires an nvidia device as the OP is asking for OpenCL (and might not have an Nvidia device).